# XML URL into PHP Array

Tags: php, xml

long time searcher ... first post... I'm stuck..

Here is a sample of my xml link :

```html
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/Deals/getRecords">  
  <result>
    <Deals>
      <row no="1">
        <FL val="DEALID">1338246000003618134</FL>
        <FL val="Deal Name">Again Holdings</FL>
      </row>
      <row no="2">
        <FL val="DEALID">1338246000003599435</FL>
        <FL val="Deal Name">Yankee Doodle</FL>
      </row>
......
```

I'm trying to create a loop to retrieve "DEALID" and "Deal Name".
I've had some success with this loop, getting the correct count of records :

```html
<?php
$result = simplexml_load_file($xml_link) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($result->result->Deals->row as $row) {
   var_dump($row);
   echo "<br>NEXT ROW<br>";
}
?>
```

Now I can't find a way to pull out the values of "DEALID" and "Deal Name" per record....  any help would be amazing.

~ An aspiring developer but still a rookie....

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$result = simplexml_load_file($xml_link) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$newArray = [];
foreach($result->result->Deals->row as $row) {
   $newRow = [];
   foreach($row as $key => $value) {
       $newRow[$key] = $value;
    }
    $newArray[] = $newRow;
}
?>
```

Comment: it swaps between Deal Name and DEAL ID, both in FL tags in the same row tag....  thank you for the help.  I can make this work.

Comment: that is my mistake. It wouldn't be set up as key value pair  but you would need to use something like `$row->getName()` I will post another answer

Answer (score 0):

The Cringe on the code is real, but sometimes it's gonna be sloppy... but it works.... about to try Xanfars suggestion above in a minute.

```html
<?php
$xml_link = "https://not_the_link.xml )";

$result = simplexml_load_file($xml_link) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$Project_Name = array();
$Project_ID = array();
$record_count = 0;

foreach($result->result->Deals->row as $row) {
 $fl_count = 0; 
 foreach($row->FL as $record) {
  if ($fl_count == 0){
   $Project_ID[$record_count] = $record;
  }
  if ($fl_count == 1){
   $Project_Name[$record_count] = $record; 
  }
  $fl_count=1;
 }
 echo 'Project Name : '.$Project_Name[$record_count].'<br>';
 echo 'Project ID : '.$Project_ID[$record_count].'<br>-------------------<br>';
 $record_count = $record_count+1;
}
Echo $record_count;
?>
```

Comment: $xml_link = "https://not_the_link.xml )"; why is there a close bracket?

Answer (score 0):

See if this is any better :)

```
$result = simplexml_load_file($xml_link) or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$newArray = [];
foreach($result->result->Deals->row as $row) {
   $newRow = [];
   foreach($row as $value) {
       $key = $value->attributes();
       $newRow[$key->val] = $value;
    }
    $newArray[] = $newRow;
}
```

EDIT:
I had to change this sorry not in a testing environment right now